# Запуск .exe из C++

Tags: c++, windows, exe

Как запустить *.ехе* файл из C++? Знаю о существовании `StartProcess`, но не могу понять как добавить параметры командной строки.

Например, мне нужно запустить `tesseract.exe` с параметрами:

```
img1.jpg out -l rus --oem 2
```

Comment: Поскольку вы говорите об `.exe`, добавил метку [tag:windows]. Если вас интересуют и другие платформы, укажите это в вопросе явно и уберите эту метку.

Comment: Может быть в имеете в виду [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Простое решение - использовать функцию [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/), в вашем случае:

```
system("tesseract.exe img1.jpg out -l rus --oem 2");
```

Кроссплатформенное решение - [Boost.Process](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/process.html)

Позволяет:

- создавать дочерние процессы
- настраивать потоки ввода/вывода для дочерних процессов
- взаимодействовать с дочерними процессами с помощью потоков ввода/вывода (синхронно и асинхронно)
- ожидать завершения процесса (синхронно и асинхронно)
- прерывать процесс

Пример:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

using namespace boost::process;

int main()
{
    ipstream pipe_stream;
    child c("gcc --version", std_out > pipe_stream);

    std::string line;

    while (pipe_stream && std::getline(pipe_stream, line) && !line.empty())
        std::cerr << line << std::endl;

    c.wait();
}
```

Comment: Вроде system менее производительней чем startprocess

Comment: На производительность запущенного процесса не влияет то как вы его запускаете - с помощью system или StartProcess. Но, в случае system, действительно может оказаться дополнительная задержка на запуск 
 из-за дополнительного кода между вызовом system и StartProcess (который в итоге будет вызван). По сравнению с инициализацией/выполнением процесса эта задержка ничтожна.

Answer (score 1):

Не хотите воспользоваться [`_spawnl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wweek9sc.aspx)?

В вашем случае -

```
#include <process.h>

....

intptr_t rc = _spawnl(P_WAIT,"tesseract.exe","tesseract.exe",
                      "img1.jpg","out","-l","rus","--oem","2",NULL);
```

В отличие от `system` вернет информацию о выполнении.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно указать "\"tesseract\" img1.jpg out -l rus --oem 2" в качестве запускаемого приложения. Такой вариант тоже может сработать, хотя у CreateProcess'a есть нужные аргументы для передачи параметров запуска.

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

```
system("start tesseract.exe img1.jpg out -l rus --oem 2");
```

Но контроля над созданным процессом нет.

Comment: Что подразумевается под контролем?

Comment: Иметь айди или дескриптор процесса. Чтобы убить процесс например.